# List the differences between two Git repos (all branches)

Tags: git

Is there a simple way to see all differences between 2 Git repos (all branches & tags considered)?  I know there are several questions on SO that relate to this, but in the end, they all seem to be comparing on a branch basis (ex: git log remote/master...master).  I'm looking for something that can list all the differences between the repos.

The use case is that I have a vendor that shipped me a Git repo a while back.  Since then, I'm not sure where development has occurred (in my local Git repo or in their repo or in both).  I want to compare all branches to see what has changed.

Is there a simple Git way of doing this, or am I limited to scripting this out to extract the name of each branch and comparing branch by branch?

Comment: Branches—or more specifically and accurately, branch *names* —are just names for one specific commit. The actual commit IDs are the hash IDs. The *names* let you, and Git, get started in terms of finding the commits. What you must do is compare the commits, and the easy way to do that is to *combine* any two repositories' commits into one bigger repository. The `git fetch` command, which takes the name of a "remote"—a peer repository, with associated URL—does exactly that: gets their commits, by their branch names, and copies the ones you don't have into *your* repository, under [cont'd]

Comment: ... under similar but slightly-modified names, which are your *remote-tracking branch names*, such as `origin/master` or `peer/master` or whatever. Now, given that they gave you a whole repository earlier, you can treat that as its own separate thing, use that to add their newer repository to their older repository (assuming they did not just start over), and by seeing what gets added, see exactly what they did.

Comment: @torek I'm not sure I follow; are you saying that the branch name is only a reference to a single commit ID?

Comment: Yes. The target commit for a branch name changes as new commits are added to the branch. Each commit contains, as part of its metadata, the commit ID(s) of its parent commit(s). These form a backwards chain of commits, so that by starting at the most recent, i.e., *tip* commit, Git can find the *rest* of the commits that are considered to be on / contained-within that branch. Note that one commit can therefore be on *many* branches simultaneously, through these back-pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to a different branch, delete all the files (except the `.git` folder) then copy and paste all of their files into your repo (except the `.git` folder) and commit it on that separate branch.

Then you can use any of the numerous ways to diff two branches against each other. It's kind of hacky, but works surprisingly well.

If you want, you can then delete the branch when your done.